# Using awk to split column, count occurrences

Tags: count, awk, split

I have an input file in the form:

```
type   count
"apples, oranges, bananas"   3  
oranges   5  
"apples, bananas"   10  
"oranges, bananas"   2
```

and I am trying to calculate the total number of apples, oranges, and bananas in the file (the first column is comma-separated). So the output should look something like:

```
apples   13  
oranges   10  
bananas   15
```

I am having trouble coming up with a simple awk expression to sum over the unique elements of the split column. Any thoughts?

Comment: is there a `,` missing from line 2?

Comment: no, there are no commas at the end of the first column

Comment: @user2232814 End of *last* column, right?

Comment: i edited to make the columns clearer. there are only two columns in my input file.

Comment: Is the separator a `\t`, or just spaces? And, are all the lists of fruits embraced by double quotes?

Comment: no quotes for single fruits, and the separators are tabs.

Comment: @user2232814 Just found, that you changed the input text......... good luck man.

Comment: -1 Thanks to respect us and not breaking the rules every 5 minutes (sample input changed)

Comment: ? I didn't downvote your response...

Comment: @user2232814 - perhaps you didn't downvote but you changed the input-format several times making answers obsolete. People spent some time helping you and we became frustrated. Please, don't do this in the future; read through your text before posting and make sure that everything needed to solve the problem is included!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the input file at least twice however given the current format:

```
$ cat -t file
type^Icount
"apples, oranges, bananas"^I3
oranges^I5
"apples, bananas"^I10
"oranges, bananas"^I2
```

Note: `cat -t` shows the tabs in the file as `^I`.

This script will do the job:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{gsub(/"/,"");n=split($1,s,/, /);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)a[s[i]]+=$2}END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file
apples 13
bananas 15
oranges 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it with GNU awk:

```
<infile awk -v FS='["\t ,]+' '
NR>1 {
  for(i=1; i<NF; i++)
    if(length($i)>0)
      h[$i] += $NF
}

END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }'
```

Output:

```
apples 13
bananas 15
oranges 10
```

Note that you may need to remove trailing space before the input reaches awk:

```
<infile sed 's/[\t ]*$//' | awk -v FS='["\t ,]+' '
NR>1 { 
  for(i=1; i<NF; i++) 
    if(length($i)>0) 
      h[$i] += $NF
} 

END { for(k in h) print k, h[k] }'
```